# add attribute to xml element inside sequence in complextype

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have an xsd:

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to add an attribute "Attribute1" to "firstname" element:

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="Attribute1" type="xs:string/>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

While doing this, I'm receiving an error : 'The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attribute' element is not supported in this context.'

What is the correct way to assign attribute to the element "firstname"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few intermediate nested elements are missing. The element `firstname` must be defined with an anonymous complex type, a simple content that is a string (more exactly, the type is derived by extension from `xs:string`), and the attribute added.

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute name="Attribute1" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the original definition, if the element `firstname` has type `xs:string`, this does not allow any attribute.